# Setting the background image of an element in React js to an image stored in a variable

Tags: reactjs, header, background-image, inline-styles

this is my react element I'm trying to set a background image of

```
<header className="App-header"  style ={{ backgroundImage: "url(/${image2})"}}>
```

this is the variable that the image is stored in

```
const [image2, setImage2] = useState("./cryptolines.jpg");
```

How to I set the inline style backgroundImage to that image in the variable

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use template literals for your string.

Going by your example above, your are almost there. Replace your " with backticks instead (`)

```
<header className="App-header"  style ={{ backgroundImage: `url(/${image2})`}}></header>
```